# Books on Multi-Commodity Minimum Cost Flow Problems

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, linear-programming, network-flow

I'm searching for books on Multi-Commodity Minimum Cost Flow Problems (MCMCF) with theoretical aspects (solvability, optimality conditions, similar statements like in the case of Min Cost Flow,...). Most of the sources I found don't consider any theoretical aspects - starting with the definition of (MCMCF) they go on with solution methods.

Can you recommend good books (or the like) to me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I may be way off base, but have you looked at Harrison's Brownian Motion and Stochastic Flow Systems?

Comment: @Trurl: I had a look at the content. I don't think that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013617549X) is a great introduction to flows and there is a chapter on multi commodity flows.

Comment: Thanks - this is really good one!